# Flyway case-sensitive database name

Tags: flyway

Is it possible to have a database name as case-sensitive?

For example, in `flyway.conf`

If I declare a schema as:

```
flyway.schemas=MySpecialDB
```

Datebase is then generated as `myspecialdb` but the desired name is `MySpecialDB`.

This is observed when using `MySQL`.

Answer (score 0):

This sound's like your DB is configured to store table names in lower case. Checkout `lower_case_table_names` in the [official MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) for more information.